# How to DirectoryIndex a controler route?

Tags: .htaccess, symfony, apache2, directoryindex

With my current configuration every time I typed something.com it shows the app_dev.php which is right because of my current rewrite rule. But what I want is if a user typed www.something.com it will automatically direct to www.something.com/home

note: 'home' is a route under one of my bundle

**This are my current configurations**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  # Admin email, Server Name (domain name), and any aliases
  ServerAdmin admin@something.com
  ServerName  www.something.com

  # Index file and Document Root (where the public files are located)
#  DirectoryIndex home    # I have already tried this, nothing happens
  DocumentRoot /home/user/public/something.com/web/symfony/web

  # Log file locations
  LogLevel warn
  ErrorLog  /home/user/public/something.com/log/error.log
  CustomLog /home/user/public/something.com/log/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

**.htaccess inside Symfony/web**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteRule ^$ app.php/home [L]

    Options +FollowSymlinks
    RewriteEngine On

    # Explicitly disable rewriting for front controllers
   RewriteRule ^app_dev.php - [L]
   RewriteRule ^app.php - [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

    # Change below before deploying to production
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app.php [QSA,L]
    #RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app_dev.php [QSA,L]

</IfModule>
```

the actual url must be www.something.com/app.php/home (the current rules hid the app.php)

EDIT: Updated the .htaccess base on the answers given. but still not working

Answer (score 0):

Insert a `RewriteRule` at the top

```
RewriteRule ^$ home [L]
```

This will redirect to `/home`, if you want the client to see this URL, you must add a [`R`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_r) flag to the rule.

Comment: it returns /home not found in this server. Actually what my original url looks is www.something.com/app.php . my current configuration hides app.php and i need to have that in every page. In short i should have www.something.com/app.php/home when i tried what u suggested. it removes the app.php

Comment: still not working. 404 not found. here's the actual link --> cloud-pod.net returns 404 but cloud-pod.net/home returns the page.

Comment: still the same. when I look on my apache error log. nothing is actually being reported.

Comment: @Saber All these rules, the previous one as well as this one, work in my test environment, so I don't know what's wrong here. Anyway, I'm out of ideas, sorry.

Comment: Thanks Anyway. I am so wondering what probably is causing it not to work.

Answer (score 0):

In your .htaccess or VirtualHost, use `mod_alias` to get a temporary redirect (302). You won't have to worry about it conflicting with your application URL rewriting.

```
Redirect / /home
```

See http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_alias.html